# Run function in script from command line (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I'm writing a web app in Node. If I've got some JS file `db.js` with a function `init` in it how could I call that function from the command line?

Comment: use npm run-func https://stackoverflow.com/a/43598047/696535

Comment: @Pawel I prefer the accepted answer because it doesn't require installing a third party dependency which may either lose support or contain vulnerabilities. It's a risk you run with any dependency, so limiting dependencies to well vetted and maintained ones is always a good idea.

Comment: You could also use the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/invoke-script

Answer (score 539, accepted):

No comment on why you want to do this, or what might be a more standard practice: here is a solution to your question.... Keep in mind that the type of quotes required by your command line may vary.

In your `db.js`, export the `init` function. There are many ways, but for example:

```js
    module.exports.init = function () {
      console.log('hi');
    };
```

Then call it like this, assuming your `db.js` is in the same directory as your command prompt:

```
node -e 'require("./db").init()'
```

If your `db.js` were a module `db.mjs`, use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) to load the module:

```js
node -e 'import("./db.mjs").then( loadedModule => loadedModule.init() )'
```

To other readers, the OP's  `init` function could have been called anything, it is not important, it is just the specific name used in the question.

Comment: This was a useful tip for testing some javascript that was running from AWS lambda - thanks

Comment: What happens if the function is async?

Comment: In case anyone else is trying to do this in their package.json as a npm script, I tried it with the single quotes, and double quotes inside, but it didn't work until I switched them: "start": "node -e \"require('./server')()\"",

Comment: Got an error 'TypeError: require(...).init is not a function'

Comment: @C.Lee is init a function in your script?

Comment: @winhowes  Yes, init is just part of the the example posted - could be called anything, just an entry point to the script.

Comment: @LeeGee yep - was more just helping @C.Lee debug - as they might not realize that `init` was a function in the script file

Comment: Thanks @winhowes for your reply, I just used your example
`module.exports.init = function () {
  console.log('hi');
};`
And `node -e 'require("./db").init()'` didn't work for me somehow. 
I am not sure what I did wrong, but by following your idea, I used `module.exports = myFunction, `, and then `node -e 'require("./myFunction")()'` worked for me.

Comment: as an augmentation to @AlexHinton's comment, I now use the following to mimick an event and the callback: `node -e 'require("./index").handler(require("./fixtures/sample_event_01.json"), {}, console.log)'`. The middle `{}` would be the context, feel free to adjust. Also console.log is a bit primitive but a nice start.
Of course you can also write a dedicate CLI.js that in turn require()'s the index.js/handler as stated in other comments.

Comment: @LeeGee Here is a perfect example: I have a script I want to run. For my own reasons I decided I'd like to write it in javascript. Now I want to run it. I happen to have a particular application in mind which is what led me here.

Comment: @ToKra — Add to you `package.json`'s `scripts` node the following: `"example": "node -e 'require(\"./db\").init()' "` — YMMV with the escaped quotes!

Comment: node -p instead of node -e prints the result:
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_p_print_script

Comment: can I pass parameters to that init function? how do I do that?

Comment: @Patlatus - just put them in the parentheses ...init("foo",123).

Comment: I've used sth like this ``"node -e 'require(\"./handler\").findMostSuitableLinkStation()'"`` for testing before uploading to AWS lambda, but it didn't work!!!!

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger, A bit late to the party, but if it's a promise it would go something like `node -e 'require("./db").init().then(x=>{console.log(x)})'` then you'll have to ctrl+c out of the script or do `node -e 'require("./db").init().then(x=>{console.log(x);process.exit()})'`

Comment: If I return something in init(), how can I obtain it?

Comment: In windows, I can only make it by `node -e require('./db').init()` or `node -e "require('./db').init()"`. Pay attention to single quote and double quote.

Comment: @newman In my windows, I failed with `node -e require('./db').init()` but `node -e "require('./db').init()"` works. And additionally `node -e 'require(\"./db\").init()'` also works.

Comment: ``npx run-func /path/to/folder/file.js myfunction `` This worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 88):

**Update 2020 - CLI**

As @mix3d pointed out you can just run a command where `file.js` is your file and `someFunction` is your function optionally followed by parameters separated with spaces

```js
npx run-func file.js someFunction "just some parameter"
```

That's it.

`file.js` called in the example above

```js
const someFunction = (param) => console.log('Welcome, your param is', param)

// exporting is crucial
module.exports = { someFunction }
```

**More detailed description**

**Run directly from CLI (global)**

Install

```
npm i -g run-func
```

Usage i.e. run function "init", it must be exported, see the bottom

```
run-func db.js init
```

or

**Run from package.json script (local)**

Install

```
npm i -S run-func
```

Setup

```
"scripts": {
   "init": "run-func db.js init"
}
```

Usage

```
npm run init
```

**Params**

Any following arguments will be passed as function parameters `init(param1, param2)`

```
run-func db.js init param1 param2
```

**Important**

the function (in this example `init`) must be exported in the file containing it

```
module.exports = { init };
```

or ES6 export

```
export { init };
```

Comment: I was thinking to use eye_mew' suggestion to use `make-runnable`, but this is a lot better than that, me thinks. Thanks.

Comment: @luis.espinal I'm glad you find this useful. There's less magic in the background and no need to modify files. Unless a function is not exported then it has to be, but that makes logical sense just like regular ES6 modules and their import/export.

Comment: this doesn't work for me; $ run-func db.js init
bash: run-func: command not found

Comment: @Patlatus to use directly from CLI without a script in package.json install it globally `npm i -g run-func`

Comment: @Patlatus actually there was a bug that was only allowing this to run inside package.json scripts. I uploaded a new version that fixes it and it works globally too

Comment: Thanks to `npx`, we can do `npx run-func file.js functionName` without having to install run-func globally. #winning!

Comment: @mix3d wow I haven't build this functionality intentionally but it works like that too !

Comment: You should mention, that you are one of the contributors of package [`run-func`](https://github.com/DVLP/run-func)...

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: @JerryGreen have you tried changing extension to .mjs?

Comment: @Pawel I have TypeScript, I can't rename it to `.mjs`

Comment: @JerryGreen It seems like your exported files are in ES6 modules which must be in .mjs to work as modules or you can change the output target to ES5 in typescript and then it will work with .js files

Comment: @Pawel nah, it just doesn't work with typescript. I tried to use ts-node, but it doesn't help

Comment: @JerryGreen so you're trying to run a typescipt file in Node directly without transpiling? It's not going to work like that

Comment: @Pawel I have webpack for that. But I don't have js sources before I start my application, so I have to either transpile it by running `tsc` compiler (which is meh), or I can use `ts-node`, but I can't get it working either. Whatever. I'll figure some way

Comment: @Pawel do you have idea how to run it if function is ES6 module and is importing something from another module for example `import { mockApi } from "@/api/instances";` ?

Comment: You can also do `export function1(){..}`

Comment: ``npx run-func /path/to/folder/file.js myfunction `` This worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 78):

As per the other answers, add the following to `someFile.js`

```
module.exports.someFunction = function () {
  console.log('hi');
};
```

You can then add the following to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
   "myScript": "node -e 'require(\"./someFile\").someFunction()'"
}
```

From the terminal, you can then call

```
npm run myScript
```

I find this a much easier way to remember the commands and use them

Comment: On my Win10 machine, this syntax is simply echoing the script (in either a PowerShell or Command Prompt terminal). Running it directly instead of via 'npm run' throws 'Unexpected token' pointing to the start of the require parameter. I haven't figured out how to make it work yet.

Comment: @CalvinDale same here except I can run the script itself in powershell just fine.

Comment: On my machine (Windows 10) i had to switch the double- and single-quotes, like this: "myScript": "node -e \"require('./someFile').someFunction()\""
Otherwise Node would just print out the command inside the single-quotes but not evaluate it. Maybe this solves the issues of @CalvinDale and ferr.

Comment: What if we want to add an argument to the function call?

Answer (score 38):

Try [make-runnable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-runnable).

In db.js, add `require('make-runnable');` to the end.

Now you can do:

```
node db.js init
```

Any further args would get passed to the `init` method, in the form of a list or key-value pairs.

Answer (score 27):

Sometimes you want to run a function via CLI, sometimes you want to `require` it from another module. Here's how to do both.

```
// file to run
const runMe = () => {}
if (require.main === module) {
  runMe()
} 
module.exports = runMe
```

Answer (score 19):

This one is dirty but works `:)`

I will be calling `main()` function from my script. Previously I just put calls to main at the end of script. However I did add some other functions and exported them from script (to use functions in some other parts of code) - but I dont want to execute main() function every time I import other functions in other scripts.

So I did this,
in my script i removed call to main(), and instead at the end of script I put this check:

```
if (process.argv.includes('main')) {
   main();
}
```

So when I want to call that function in CLI: `node src/myScript.js main`

Comment: For me is enough, and does not force double quotes escapes in `package.json` scripts

Comment: I don't think this is dirty at all. It's simple and explicit and it works. :-)

Comment: You have no idea how much you helped me with this idea! Thank you so much!!

Comment: This is IMHO the most practical answer

Answer (score 11):

simple way:

let's say you have db.js file in a helpers directory in project structure.

now go inside helpers directory and go to node console

```
 helpers $ node
```

2) require db.js file

```
> var db = require("./db")
```

3) call your function (in your case its init())

```
> db.init()
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

If you turn `db.js` into a module you can require it from `db_init.js` and just: `node db_init.js`.

db.js:

```
module.exports = {
  method1: function () { ... },
  method2: function () { ... }
}
```

db_init.js:

```
var db = require('./db');

db.method1();
db.method2();
```

Answer (score 10):

Updated for 2022 - If you've switched to ES Modules, you can't use the require tricks, you'd need to use dynamic imports:

```
node -e 'import("./db.js").then(dbMod => dbMod.init());'
```

or with the --experimental-specifier-resolution=node flag:

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node -e 'import("./db").then(dbMod => dbMod.init());'
```

Answer (score 7):

I do a IIFE, something like that:

```
(() => init())();
```

this code will be executed immediately and invoke the init function.

Comment: But if you run: `node init.js` and the file contains an IIFE it will work. I think that I didn't fully understand your question. Sorry.

Comment: Totally get that, but if the code contains other functions they may or may not be called

Comment: You can even simplify it into `(init)();` if you want :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also run TypeScript with `ts-node` similar to @LeeGoddard [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480927/4396730).
In my case, I wanted to use `app` and `init` separately for testing purposes.

```js
// app.ts

export const app = express();

export async function init(): Promise<void> {
   // app init logic...
}
```

```
// commonjs
npx ts-node -e 'require("./src/app").init();'
// esmodule
npx ts-node -e 'import("./src/app").then(a => a.init());'
```

Comment: Not necessary to use npx, can just do `ts-node -e 'require("./index.ts").run();'`

Comment: Npx will provide consistent reproducibility for `ts-node` unless a global binary of it has been installed.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this method is not what you mean, but who knows it can help

#### index.js

```js
const arg = process.argv.splice(2);

function printToCli(text){
    console.log(text)
}

switch(arg[0]){
    case "--run":
        printToCli("how are you")
    break;
    default: console.log("use --run flag");
}
```

and run command `node . --run`

#### command line

```sh
probuss-MacBook-Air:fb_v8 probus$ node . --run
how are you
probuss-MacBook-Air:fb_v8 probus$
```

and you can add more arg[0] , arg[1], arg[2] ... and more

for `node . --run -myarg1 -myarg2`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include environment variables from your .env files, you can use [`env-cmd`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd):

```
npx env-cmd node -e 'require("./db").init()'
```

If you want run a specific function in the file too, use [`run-func`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-func):

```
npx env-cmd npx run-func db.js init someArg
```

Or, to provide an argument for the accepted answer you'd have to do something like:

```
npx env-cmd node -e 'require("./db").init(someArg)'
```

Writing/updating an expression here is less explicit (so easier to miss when you're checking back, for example) than providing different arguments to the commands, so I recommend using `env-cmd` with `run-func`.

*Note: I also usually add `--experimental-modules` on the end when necessary.*

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by https://github.com/DVLP/run-func/blob/master/index.js

I create https://github.com/JiangWeixian/esrua

if file `index.ts`

```
export const welcome = (msg: string) => {
  console.log(`hello ${msg}`)
}
```

just run

```
esrua ./index.ts welcome -p world
```

will output `hello world`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30409373)

Comment: This is good for running functions in `ts` files from cmd. It seems that ts-node is behind the scenes working.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the other answers here, if you wanted to make this reusable you could create a script as follows:

```js
// rn-fn.js
const [, , filePath, fn, ...args] = process.argv;
import(filePath).then((mod) => mod[fn](...args));
```

Then as an example:

```js
// hello.js
export function hello(str) {
  console.log(`hello ${str}`)
}
```

Running:

```
node ./rn-fn.js ./hello.js hello world
```

at the command line should then return

```
hello world
```

Answer (score -2):

If your file just contains your function, for example:

myFile.js:

```
function myMethod(someVariable) {
    console.log(someVariable)
}
```

Calling it from the command line like this nothing will happen:

```
node myFile.js
```

But if you change your file:

myFile.js:

```
myMethod("Hello World");

function myMethod(someVariable) {
    console.log(someVariable)
}
```

Now this will work from the command line:

```
node myFile.js
```

Comment: Sure, that's how to run a JS file. The question was more aimed at whether I could run a specific function (out of many possible functions) where the only change was to the command line input rather than JS file itself per function call

Comment: This is not dealing with the scenario the person is asking for

Comment: @jobmo it is, they want to run a method from the cmd line, this does that. ( i got here by googling the question myself, so someone else might appreciate the answer), don't worry there are a diverse set of answers you are allowed to have a choice

Comment: Exactly, the question is about running a method from the cmd line. In this answer,  myFile.js is executed.That's it. It is no executing any function. It happens then that the file has a function and the function is called inside the file. That was my point.

Comment: You just explained that the answer executions the function from the command line :+1: