# Determine & change DocumentRoot/port of node.js & run a function w/parameters

Tags: node.js

How do I determine and change both the "DocumentRoot" equivalent (of Apache) *and* port number on Node.js? I need to test a script file by calling the function and passing some parameters (yes, I know the file can execute it automatically).

There is no "getting started" or mention of this in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I first installed Node.js and it just has a command prompt in Windows. Still not sure the port number.

Node seems to execute scripts from it's directory (e.g. `C:\Node.js\`). As James mentioned in another answer Node.js doesn't do much on it's own. I followed a [tutorial on getting Express to work on Windows](https://coderwall.com/p/mbov6w/running-nodejs-and-express-on-windows). The tutorial failed to mention *where* scripts are run from so ignore the directions past running the following on the *normal* command prompt (not Node's console):

1. `Run npm install`
2. `npm install express -g`
3. `npm install url -g`
4. `npm install fresh -g`
5. `npm install cookie -g`
6. `npm install methods -g`
7. `npm install crc -g`
8. `npm install send -g`
9. `npm install connect -g`
10. `npm install commander -g`
11. `npm i -D run-func`

Okay, the last line of code allows us to run a function and pass parameters which I found via [Pawel's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782693/run-function-in-script-from-command-line-node-js#answer-43598047).

So now I can execute the following:

```
node run-func "C:\Users\John\HTTP\index.js" function_name param1 param2
```

Comment: Installing these modules globally is _not_ a good practice. Modules should be installed local to the project they apply to.

Answer (score 3):

Apache HTTPD is a generic web server. Node.js is a development framework that includes a standard library for creating HTTP servers. Thus, there isn't a standard configuration for a Node.js based application like there is for Apache HTTPD.

The basic example of writing a web server with Node.js is found at https://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html#synopsis_example

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Which is to say, *you* define where files are loaded from and what port they are served over.

This is where frameworks like [Fastify](https://fasitfy.io), [Hapi](https://hapijs.com), and [Express](https://expressjs.com/) come in. The make it easier to write generic web servers.

Comment: A friend advised Express and I followed the directions here: https://coderwall.com/p/mbov6w/running-nodejs-and-express-on-windows however `C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\Node.js>node app module.js:540 throw err; Error: Cannot find module`. I'm not interested in setting up a VM, I want to run it locally on Windows. What part of that tutorial is missing?

Comment: Ah: `node "C:\Users\example\index.js"` ... so how do I execute a function named `callWeatherApi(city, date)` then? I can fill my own parameters. That is really what I'm ultimately asking though I try to keep things fairly simple since I knew it would not be as straight-forward as Apache.

Comment: Apache HTTPD is an application not a development framework. They are not equivalent. Use https://nodeschool.io/ to learn Node.js.

Comment: While what you posted helps it skips some steps so I will up-vote it and accept the answer I posted myself. I think that is fair, granted it was a difficult to ask question to begin with. Thank you.

Comment: You changed the question after it had been answered. One cannot accomplish a goal when it keeps moving. Testing should be done with a library like http://www.node-tap.org/